# Poisson equation with vector as an argument of charge density

Tags: electrostatics, maxwell-equations, debye-length

I want to solve the Poisson equation with the following charge density:
$$
\rho(\vec{r})=q\delta(\vec{r}-\vec{r_i})-q\frac{1}{4\pi r^2_D}
\frac{e^{-|\vec{r}-\vec{r_i}|/r_D}}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r_i}|}
$$
So I think the first step is to let $\vec{r_i}$ be zero and in the end transfer it back to $\vec{r_i}$ being free to choose again. My problem is that the density has the position as an argument and the potential should only have the radius as an argument. Transformation into spherical coordinates doesn't work here. I’ve also tried using some Fourier transformation with
$$
\delta(\vec{r})=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\int{}e^{i\vec{k}\vec{r}}d^3k=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\int{}e^{ikr\cos\alpha}d^3k
$$
but... the $\alpha$.
I hope somebody has a tip about how to tackle this problem cause I’m really out of ideas.

Comment: The density is spherically symmetric about $r_i$, so surely spherical coordinates are the way to go. Why do you say that they "don't work"? Can you show your working?

Comment: oh. thats embarassing of me. if tried spherical coordinates before asuming that $\vec{r_i}=0$. youre right. it works very well. but only and only if $\vec{r_i}=0$ right ? just want to be sure not to make another mistake

Comment: Yes. You need $r_i=0$.

Comment: @petermafai try $z=r-r_i$ and solve for $\rho(z)$. Also, because the equation is linear, you can do $\rho=\rho_1+\rho_2$ and solve independently.