# Poisson equation of point charge using Fourier transformation

Tags: electrostatics, fourier-transform, gauss-law

i have problems applying the fourier transformation. all these integrals confuse me. so here is my calculation:

$$
\Delta\phi(r)=-4\pi\delta(r)
$$
$$
\text{Left hand side}:-\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3/2}}\int_{}^{}e^{ikr}k^2\tilde{\phi}(k) dk
$$
$$
\text{Right hand side}: =-\frac{4\pi}{(2\pi)^3}\int_{}^{}e^{ikr} dk=-\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3/2}}\int_{}^{}e^{ikr}4\pi*(2\pi)^{-3/2} dk
$$
$$
\Rightarrow\tilde{\phi}(k)=\frac{4\pi*(2\pi)^{-3/2}}{k^2}
$$
$$
\phi(r)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3/2}}\int_{}^{}e^{ikr}\tilde{\phi}(r) dk=\frac{4\pi}{(2\pi)^{3}}\int_{}^{}e^{ikr}\frac{1}{k^2} dk
$$
and if i calculate this integral i dont get the expected result ($\phi(r)\sim\frac{1}{r}$)

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/640203/2451

Comment: yeah. thats also my post ^^ there i calculated the result without the use of fourier and it worked after they helped me. but now i want to calculate it with fourier

Comment: [This](http://sepwww.stanford.edu/public/docs/sep103/jon3/paper_html/node3.html) might be helpful (although admittedly the webpage there is ugly).

Answer (score 3):

First let me write the first equation correctly

$$\Delta\phi(\vec{r})=-4\pi\delta^{(3)}(\vec{r})\tag{1},$$

and [note that $\delta^{(3)}(\vec{r})\neq\delta(r)$](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_de_Dirac#Propiedades)  (sorry I couldn't find it on the english Wikipedia). For the left hand side we have

$$\phi(\vec{r})=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3/2}}\int\tilde\phi(\vec{k})e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}}d^3\vec{k}\tag{2}$$

$$\Delta\phi(\vec{r})=-\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3/2}}\int k^2\tilde\phi(\vec{k})e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}}d^3\vec{k},\tag{3}$$

where $k=|\vec{k}|$. On the other hand, the delta function is

$$\delta^{(3)}(\vec{r})=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3}}\int e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}}d^3\vec{k}\tag{4},$$

so you get $$\tilde{\phi}(\vec{k})=\frac{4\pi(2\pi)^{3/2}}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{k^2}\tag{5}.$$

Now, using $(2)$

$$\phi(\vec{r})=\frac{4\pi}{(2\pi)^3}\int\frac{1}{k^2} e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}}d^3\vec{k}=\frac{4\pi·2\pi}{(2\pi)^3}\int_0^\pi \sin\theta ~d\theta\int_0^\infty k^2~dk \frac{1}{k^2} e^{ikr\cos\theta}=\\= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-1}^1 dx\int_0^\infty dk~e^{ikrx}=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{ikr}-e^{-ikr}}{ikr}~dk=\frac{2}{\pi r}\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(kr)}{k} dk\tag{6}=\frac{1}{r},$$

where you can find the last integral [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral#Sine_integral).

Comment: in equation (6) i cant quite follow after the second =. so i assume you did transformation in spherical coordinates that where the sin and k^2 and 2pi come from. but why did you replace the cos with an x after the third =. i would have thought that you also need to integrate over the e term when you are integrating over $\theta$

Comment: $\cos\theta=x~~\Rightarrow~~-\sin\theta~d\theta=dx$, so you have to integrate $e^{ikrx}$ between $-1$ and $1$.

Comment: okay. i think i got it now. just one more thing. how do i know under which angle i need to integrate the cos. because in spherical coordinates you have 2 angles. and i wouldnt have know which one to choose

Comment: $\vec{r}$ is a fixed vector (since the integral involves $\vec{k}$), so you can choose it on the $Z$ axis, and now the angle between $\vec{r}$ and $\vec{k}$ is the polar angle.